# AngularJS delay view display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My controller fetch data from two external JSON files, filter it and then should render on the view. But whole operation take some time (approximately 30 mil sec) and view is loaded first. So data cannot be found by HTML code.

How can I delay loading of my view in order to load data from controller first?  Or maybe there is another solution?

```
$scope.ratePlansRelated = [];

$http.get('rooms.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.rooms = res.data;
});

$http.get('ratePlans.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.ratePlans = res.data;
});

// delay calling that function in order to load data from json first
setTimeout(assignRatePlans,25);


function assignRatePlans()
{
    //filter data and assing it to $scope.ratePlansRelated here

}
```

Comment: use something like `$scope.dataHasLoaded = false` to initialize hiding your view and then when the async operation has finished set to `true` in conjunction with `ng-if`

Comment: In your case I think that the better approach is use the resolve object of the routing to load the async data, so when the controller is instantiated, your data will be available. Tell me if your are using ui router or simple ngRoute and I can show you and example.

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) which doesn't resolve until all of the input promises are resolved

```
var req1 = $http.get('ratePlans.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.ratePlans = res.data;    
});    

var req2 = $http.get('rooms.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.rooms = res.data;    
});

$q.all([req1, req2])
  .then(assignRatePlans)
  .catch(function(err){
      // do something if either request fails
  });
```

Note: Remember to inject `$q` service

Answer (score 0):

Call `assignRatePlans()` on the success of the `$http`

Try this

```
$scope.ratePlansRelated = [];
var  ratePlansDone = false;
var  roomsDone = false;


$http.get('ratePlans.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.ratePlans = res.data;
    ratePlansDone = true;
    if (roomsDone) {
        assignRatePlans();
    }
});


$http.get('rooms.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.rooms = res.data;
    roomsDone = true;
    if (ratePlansDone) {
        assignRatePlans();
    }
});



function assignRatePlans()
{
    //filter data and assing it to $scope.ratePlansRelated here

}
```